# Unable to add button to frame GUI

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I am trying to add a simple JButton to a JPanel in my program. The problem is when I run the problem, I do not see any button at all.

This is my code:

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GuiStopwatch { 
    public GuiStopwatch() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton Startbtn = new JButton("START");          
        panel.add(Startbtn);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stopwatch");

        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

May I know what did I do wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: What makes you think that there should be any button displayed? Entry point is `main` which creates JFrame and sets up its size, layout, visibility and close operation. That is all. I don't see any code responsible for adding anything else to that frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not adding the panel to the frame at any point.

EDIT
Here is the code you would need if you wanted it in a separate method:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GuiStopwatch {


private static void stopwatch(JFrame frame) {

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton Startbtn = new JButton("START");
    panel.add(Startbtn);
    frame.add(panel);

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Stopwatch");

    stopwatch(frame);

    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your answer?

Comment: You should at some point have:

`frame.add(panel);`

You are displaying the frame, but it does not contain anything.

Comment: Do I have to add the panel and frame inside the public main method?

Comment: If I put the code inside Main method, it will work without any problem. I wonder why.

Comment: It's because at no point are you calling the method GuiStopwatch();

Comment: Is there anything else I can help you with?

Comment: You said you'll add what you need?

Comment: Is it neccessary to create the panel and buttons in main method?

Comment: It is not necessary, there are a number of ways you could do it. I would do it by creating a new class that generates your UI and then create an instance of it and use it to create the UI

Comment: Do I need to create frame for the UI or I could just go with JPanel?

Comment: Yes, in swing the JFrame is the window and the JPanel is a way for you use to arrange the items you want to display.

Comment: I realized, do I need to setLayout when creating frame or panel? I am a bit confused by this concept

Comment: It is not required that you use a LayoutManager but it is highly recommended. See this link for more details on each type of layout: [Types of Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: I am aware of the types of layout. I just cannot fathom the fact how do I place the position,for example of a JButton to a location I want in my frame. In the answer you provided, the button will appear at the center top of the frame. I tried using .SetBounds to change the position of the button but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: It all depends how you want to lay it out. My favourite is using the GridBagLayout as it lets you organise your UI items in a grid. Using a flow layout it simply places the elements in a row in whatever order you added them in.

Comment: So to put in a flexible position, gridlayout is better?

Comment: It's really personal preference. I just find it easier using a grid as it lines everything up for me. If you prefer to hard code the x and y coordinates of the elements, you can set the layout to null.

Comment: Setting layout to null is a big no and a bad practice. I just want to practice using layouts. Anyway, since the button is located the the center top, can you give me an idea on how to change the position or location of the button, say to lower left or middle etc?

Answer (score 1):

You could swap things, create everything you need for your frame on the constructor, what makes the code more organized and also you can use it in other Classes, putting on main method will limit what you can do and makes the code not organized

See here an example:

```
public GuiStopwatch() {

    setTitle("Stopwatch");
    setSize(600, 600);

    // Create JButton and JPanel
    JButton button = new JButton("START");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    panel.add(button);
    this.getContentPane().add(panel);

    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    GuiStopwatch guistopwatch = new GuiStopwatch();
}
```